# Is there a mistake in Ch. 2 Exercise 41 (a) of Marcus number fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

In chapter 2, exercise 41 part (a) of Marcus *Number Fields* (English 2nd edition), the book claims that the discriminant of $\alpha$ in the number field $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ where $\alpha^3=m$ with $m$ cubefree is $-27^2m$. However, I am getting $-27m^2$, and the parts after part (a) seem to only make sense with my value. Marcus defines the discriminant of an element as follows:

$$\text{disc}(\alpha)=\text{det}\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_1(1) & \sigma_1(\alpha) & \cdots& \sigma_1(\alpha^{n-1})  \\
\sigma_2(1) & \ddots & & \vdots  \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \vdots  \\
\sigma_n(1)&\cdots &\cdots & \sigma_n(\alpha^{n-1})
\end{pmatrix}^2$$

Where $\sigma_n$ are the $n$ embeddings of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ into $\mathbb{C}$.

In the case of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ where $\alpha^3=m$, we see that the embedings are described by $\sigma_1(\alpha)=\sqrt[3]{m}$, $\sigma_2(\alpha)=\omega \sqrt[3]{m}$, and $\sigma_3(\alpha)=\omega^2\sqrt[3]{m}$ where $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$. So we have

$$
\begin{align}
\text{disc}(\alpha)=&\text{det}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \sqrt[3]{m} & \sqrt[3]{m}^2 \\
1 & \omega \sqrt[3]{m} & \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{m}^2 \\
1 & \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{m} & \omega \sqrt[3]{m}^2 \\
\end{pmatrix}^2 \\ =&(m((\omega^2 - \omega)-(\omega - \omega^2)+(\omega^2 - \omega)))^2\\ 
=&m^2(3\sqrt{3}i)^2 \\
=&-27m^2
\end{align}$$

Whereas my copy of *Number Fields* gives the answer $-27^2m$. Is this a mistake?

Comment: My copy of Marcus book from $1977$ says something different in Exercise $41$. First of all, it says that $m$ is a *cubefree* integer, $m=hk^2$ with coprime $h$ and $k$, both squarefree. Then the discriminant is $disc(a)=-27m^2$. Do you have a translated edition?

Comment: My book does mention the part about cubefree, but I had forgotten to mention that in my post. I have the 2nd edition in english.